# Energy efficiency on CPU utilization

Tags: utilization

Everybody. I really need to know this things. Is it possible to reduce power consumption by increasing CPU utilization in modern multi-core servers?And why it is possible or not?

Comment: Why would doing more work use less power?  Do you have an example environment or any reasoning behind this logic?

Comment: Actually I didn't mean total power usage like( with the increase of CPU usage of 25%, 50%, 75%, 100% the total CPU power consumption will be 100W,90W,80W,70W). I mean that the consumption rate can t be reduced like(with the increase of CPU usage of 25%,50%,75%,100% the total CPU power consumption rate will be like 100W,120W,135W,150W). I mean this. Is it possible?

Comment: The answer on this seems to answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6128960/what-is-the-relation-between-cpu-utilization-and-energy-consumption